# What are some advantages of a Blockchain Explorer built on Infura's Ethereum API over Etherscan block explorer

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, etherscan

I'm developing an Ethereum blockchain explorer with [Infura](https://infura.io/) as my backend; I also need to write a report why my choice of tools (relying on Infura) provides a better block explorer than [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/). Please if you have any experience with these two technology, as to what these advantages (or differences) are please share. Links to possible answer are also welcome. Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't provide a better choice. The most reliable source would be to run your own [geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/) node.